# "Erase disk and install elementary" partition defaults

Tags: system-installation, release-loki, disk-management

When selecting "Erase disk and install elementary" during the Loki install, what are the partition defaults used when formatting the drive?

Answer (score 1):

This is what "Erase disk and install elementary" have done in my virtual machine:

- One large primary ext4 fromated partition for / (boot and home altogether).
- One more extended partition with swap partition inside.

[image]

It will be the same on real hardware but with larger partitions size.